# Highcharts JS remove tips & squared legends for linear chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, shopify

TL;DR - want my highcharts chart to look the same as Shopify's

I'm trying to achieve two things that I have found no answer for in the docs, literally tried everything

1. I want to remove the gridlines tips that are being rendered for each entry
2. Have the legend symbol be a square (I have tried the symbolRadius, but I want to remove the line in there as well) — basically nothing that I've tried works for a line chart

[image: current state]

⬇️

[image]

Here are the `xAxis` & `legend` properties:

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mar', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul'],
    labels: {
      formatter: function () {
        return moment(this.value).isValid() ? moment(this.value).format('MMM DD') : this.value
      },
      step: getLabelStepBasedOnCategories(categories),
      staggerLines: 1,
      style: {
        color: '#637381',
      },
    },
    crosshair: {
      width: 4.3,
      color: '#DFE3E8',
    },
    gridLineDashStyle: 'dash',
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    gridLineColor: '#DFE3E8',
    tickmarkPlacement: 'inside',
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick: true,
  }
  legend: {
    symbolHeight: 12,
    symbolWidth: 12,
    symbolRadius: 3,
    itemDistance: 8,
    align: 'right',

    itemStyle: {
      fontSize: '12px',
      color: '#6d7175',
      fontWeight: 400,
      letterSpacing: '-0.5px',
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% satisfied with my solution, but I honestly found no other approach.

1.) Try the property tickInterval. With that you should be able to reduce the space between the axis ticks. (Example also in the jsfiddle).
[Link to the doc](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPixelInterval)

2.) It is possible to overwrite the legend symbol function and draw the label icon with SVG paths.

```js
Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Series.prototype, 'drawLegendSymbol', function (proceed, legend) {
    proceed.call(this, legend);


    this.legendLine.attr({
           d: ['M', 0, 10, 'h', 0, 0, 5, 5]
    }).attr({
        'stroke-width': 10
    });
});
```

[Link to the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c814dx6b/1/)

---

**Addition:**
It is also possible to overwrite the markers with an icon, the icon will also be displayed in the legend. The downside is, if you disable the markers, also the legend symbol will be disabled.

I found that solution in the Highcharts-Forums -> [to the Topic](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=40503).

---

**Edit 20. Mai 2022**

Added link to the new jsFiddle with new styled legend symbols. Add link to SVG Path-Editor tool, to simply modify SVG-Paths.

[Link to new jsfiddle with square round borders](https://jsfiddle.net/utfcrvw7/23/)

[Amazing SVG Path-Editor from GitHub user Yqnn](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/)

```
  this.legendLine.attr({
           d: ['M', 2, 2, 'L', 5, 2, 'C', 7, 2, 7, 2, 7, 4, 'L', 7, 7, 'C', 7, 9, 7, 9, 5, 9, 'L', 2, 9, 'C', 0, 9, 0, 9, 0, 7, 'L', 0, 4, 'C', 0, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2]
    }).attr({
        'stroke-width': 7
    });
});
```

Comment: Partially perfect. The `tickPixelInterval` doesn't work because the xAxis was categorized and the docs make it clear that it doesn't work for categorized items. I didn't make it perfectly clear in my example and for that I apologize (I've updated it).
However, your answer lead me to the solution, which was to replace the `step` with `tickInterval` and worked like a charm.
Now for the legend, it works! But I have no idea how to make the square have a border radius of 4px. If you update the answer, I'll mark it as accepted and will update my question as well. Thanks a bunch for the time!

Comment: I'm glad I could help, and that you found a solution with the tickInterval. About the Legend and its symbol. I want to say that I'm still not sure this is the perfect way to do - but, as mentioned before, I still have no better solution.

I'll update the fiddle with it a new path and an additional tool to try paths on your own. You're welcome, i hope it helps :)

Comment: @Ovi 
Did you have the chance to check if the solution is acceptable=

Comment: yep that works, just remember to replace `tickPixelInterval` with `tickInterval`. As stated, `tickPixelInterval` does NOT work with line charts. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Ovi You're welcome! I'll update tickIntervall in my Answer, thank you for the reminder :-)